# Select all records from one table and referenced values from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, join

2 tables:

```
table1 (id, name)
table2 (id, table1_id, unique_identifier)
```

I want to get all rows from table1 and for each to determine if I have rows in table2 which have a specific unique_identifier.

Example:

```
tabel1:
1, name1
2, name2
3, name3

table2:
1, 2, ident1
2, 3, ident2
```

I want as result:

```
name1
name2, ident1
name3, ident2
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `LEFT JOIN` for that

```
SELECT table1.name, table2.unique_identifier 
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 
ON table1.id = table2.table1_id
```

That way you'll get null on the unique identifier column if there's no corresponding record in the second table